# Execute two actions on form submit with one submit button

Tags: php, html

I have an html form on my site, so that users can subscribe to my mailing list. I'm using getResponse to build my list and send out automated emails. To do this, I put "https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" into the action attribute of my form. Here is a simplified version of my form:

```
<form action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="required">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value=“Subscribe”>
</form>
```

I also have a send.php file to insert user information into a MySQL database on my server. But since I can only specify one file in the action attribute, I don't know have to execute both getResponse script and my own script when the user clicks on Subscribe.

Basically I want to achieve the following behavior: When somebody clicks on "Subscribe", their information should get send to getResponse into my mailing list AND into the MySQL DB on my server.

I have spend hours looking online, I haven't found anything that works.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you change `add_subscriber` to a PHP file you can call your script `send.php` within there. It's difficult to answer this without seeing what you have attempted already or the contents of `add_subscriber.html` or `send.php`.

Comment: I don't have any access or control over the getResponse file https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html, it's on getResponse's server. I only have control over the file send.php which I created and is on my server.

Comment: You can either use javascript to submit the form to both, or you can submit to your own server & have your server use curl to pass the formdata to getresponse. If you do it that way, you could even store the form data in a database & use a cron job for passing data to getresponse. I'd probably just submit to my own server & curl from my server right then.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an id say `myForm`

```
<form action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_subscriber.html" method="post" id="myForm">
```

Then intercept the form's submit event and prevent the submission to app.getresponse.com, instead call ajax to your `send.php` passing the form data and once `send.php` returns submit the form to app.getresponse.com

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      //don't submit now

      //do ajax first
      $.ajax({url: '/send.php', method: $("#myForm").attr('method'), data: $("#myForm").serialize() , success: function(){
        $("#myForm").submit(); //now submit to app.getresponse.com
      }});
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I think your solution creates an infinite loop because data never gets send to getResponse and I get hundreds of identical entries in my DB for one subscriber.